# How can I call a function from inside an imported module, aka design issue

Tags: python, import

I've been trying to look for an answer to this and couldn't find anything. Maybe my approach just sucks.

I have a script which I want to write in such a way so that it's easily extensible (with modules) in the future. For that reason, I have created a function in said script that will "register" a module; basically, add a function provided by a module to a dictionary using a key provided by the module.

My initial and current plan is to call that function from the module I'm importing, which doesn't work, obviously. Can I somehow call that function from inside the module? If not, how else can I tackle this? My problem is that I have dynamic function names here and there, and I can't just call a function from a given string, so I'm creating a dictionary for that exact same purpose. For simplicity's sake, though, I'd rather just import all modules, and not do anything in addition to that in the main script.

Comment: Could you post scripts that use to import and the module itself? So we can help you easier.

Comment: The way you've phrased this question is confusing and you need to post an example of what you are trying to do before we can understand what it is you want and what you have done wrong/haven't done.

Comment: Sorry. Basically, I have what Rob suggested, but the application and master.py are both in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would have three elements in my design:

My extensible library:

```
# master.py

# List of plugins
plugins = []


# registration API called by plugin
import inspect
def register():
    frame = inspect.stack()[1]
    module = inspect.getmodule(frame[0])
    plugins.append(module)

# functional API called by application
def callout():
    for m in plugins:
        m.shout()

def dynamic_callout(s):
    for m in plugins:
        getattr(m, s[:2]+s[-3:])()
```

My plugins:

```
# plugin1.py

# Register this plugin
import master
master.register()

# Respond to request from master
def shout():
   print "Hello from", __name__
```

Finally, my application:

```
# Esablish a plugin by importing it    
import plugin1

# Call the API
import master
master.callout()
master.dynamic_callout("shut up or get out")
```

Comment: This seems like a rather elegant solution, and it works. Thanks!